# Can we insert those values without if statements?

Tags: php, algorithm, math

Hello here is an array of all values possibilities that should be an instance of the int we have as rank. But I would like this array to be empty first and find those values without if statements, so with a **smart mathematical relation**.

*Example*: a player who has the rank 3 would have those rewards: **First time**: At pos 0: 10 keys; pos 1: 13 keys; pos 2: 13 keys; 8 lives and 2 keys at pos 0 if he already registered their first time rewards.

*(In fact there would be if satement only if the player never registered their rewards).*

So I've tried to do this with digital sequences that I learned to school but it does not seems working.

**Thank you for your time... and your help !**

P.S.: I'm quite new here, sorry for any mistake.

Here is the schema of all possibilities stored in this array:

```php
$rewards = [
                1 => [
                    "count" => [7, 7, 7],
                    "lives" => 8,
                    "count_back" => [2, 2]
                ],
                2 => [
                    "count" => [7, 10, 10],
                    "lives" => 10,
                    "count_back" => [1]
                ],
                3 => [
                    "count" => [10, 13, 13],
                    "lives" => 13,
                    "count_back" => [2]
                ],
                4 => [
                    "count" => [10, 13, 13],
                    "lives" => 15,
                    "count_back" => [2]
                ],
                5 => [
                    "count" => [14, 15, 15],
                    "lives" => 18,
                    "count_back" => [2]
                ],
                6 => [
                    "count" => [16, 18, 18],
                    "lives" => 20,
                    "count_back" => [2, 2]
                ]
            ];
```

So the only input we have for this command is the player rank (int). Starting to it I would like to find without if statements, that will be too big or this complete array we have above that would take too much datas in memory for nothing (because the player doesn't have several ranks) ; the specific reward.
For example: I have the input 1. So the output should be `["count" => [7, 7, 7], "lives" => 8]` if the player never used the command. If he already used it so the output should be only `["count" => [2, 2]]`

Comment: I didn't understand what you are working on. Even the first sentence of your question: I don't understand it. I reread it several times, and I have no clue what I am reading. Is this about a game? *"instance of the int we have before"*? Before? Instance of the int? Can you please take a step back and first explain what you are working on? Also, tag your question with the appropriate programming language (`php`).

Comment: Hello, first, thank you for your response ! Sure, so I'm working on a minecraft command in game (using [PocketMine-MP](https://github.com/pmmp/PocketMine-MP/tree/stable/src/pocketmine) software written in PHP) that would give a certain reward to the command sender depending of his rank. This array would be to schematize what I'm looking for. Example: the int 1 is the VIP rank (the int is in instance of the rank). So he would receives 21 keys of the 3 tiers the first time the player uses the command; and 8 lives. (+ 4 keys of the two tiers after he uses the command back in a certain countdown).

Comment: So the old system I used is a very long switch of all the ranks rewards if the player is VIP or VIP+ etc... And now I would like to do a calcul that gives the rewards for each rank depending of his intensity (1;2;3;4;5;6) and actualize the reward array that is empty first (to avoid losing some memory due to the size of the array for all possibilities) to insert only the specific rank datas given. But I don't know what would be the algorithm and the calcul to do this. So it's for this I would like to ask it there. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: I think this question is not for me. I only know minecraft from when I see my kids play it. I have no idea what keys, tiers, command, lives, countdown, VIP rank, ... are, and how they relate to your question. Possibly a minecraft addict will find your question and can help you.

Comment: But the question is not really related to the minecraft features. It's more an algorithm question. Lives; keys; VIP are just ints we have in this array. The real question is how can we just insert the specifics datas depending of the int attribute the player has (rank) in the array rewards without using if statements and register all the possibilities in an array. Thank you anyway

Comment: Maybe I will understand if you can provide sample input and the desired output for it and the if-based code you talk about.

Comment: The message is too long so I created a paste bin. Oh and there is an error in rank 2.. I'm sorry, it is tier 2 for the last givekey if the player never used the reward command. here: https://pastebin.com/ynkUa6n7

Comment: And I can give you the entire source code I have now without explainations: https://pastebin.com/hdVJmMGb
And as you can see, it is very biiig while the player only has one rank. So it's for this I don't want to use if statements and only make a general calcul that insert in the array only the features related to the current player's rank because it would be more understandable in the code and takes less memory. I hope this is more clear now. And thank you.

Comment: There is another version with array only but here too; it would take memory for nothing. Because of the useless array ranks keys. (The player only has one rank).
Here is the paste bin: https://pastebin.com/XgRmLYX3

Comment: Finally, I can add a last pastebin where I tell you exactly what I'm trying to do. In code language: https://pastebin.com/20KiYcf9

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, but I don't see expected output. Please provide PHP notation of input (which I think you have already in your question -- or is that the expected output?), and expected output for it (using the same notation). It's good you share code, but please do so *within* your question and not behind a link. Minimise it to just revolve around the problem you have.

Comment: Yeah, I can give you a specific output for example if the player has the rank 1 and he never used the command so I would set in the array **$rewards**: `["count" => [7, 7, 7], "lives" => 10]` and if he already used the command I would set in the array: `["count" => [2, 2]`. But as I said I don't want to use if statement since there are too much conditions. So I would like to use a calcul that find the numer of count and lives from the int associated to a rank.

Comment: Can you edit your question (there is an edit link) and add a good example of input/output (related to eachother of course), so that it is abundantly clear which *transformation* you are looking for? At least, that is how far I understand your question: you have input, you have a desired output, and you are looking for nice code to make the transformation...

Comment: Right, I added some further informations in my principal question, thanks for the advise